# Celts build order on Age of Empires Online

Tags: age-of-empires-online

As per title, what is a good build order for the Celts on Age of Empires Online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a guide, from http://forums.ageofempiresonline.com/forums/permalink/262389/262389/ShowThread.aspx#262389:

1. Remember to have your Town Center to produce non-stop villagers unless you're aging up.
2. Start sending all the villagers to the bushes.
3. Select your scout and press ctrl+number (I use the number 5 for the scout). Like this you can find him just by clicking in the number (5). 
   Search the surroundings for dears and kill them with the scout. Use shift + right-click on all dears to have the scout catch'em all. (If you let the villagers to kill them, they'll just run away and the villagers will spend too much time travelling.)
   Send there up to 4 villagers to build a storehouse and shift+right-click on the dears to be sure they'll gather food after finishing building the storehouse.
4. Send all the remaining and created villagers to the woods, and build a storehouse right next to it. The closer the storehouse is to the forest, the less time your villagers travels and so the more they produce.
5. Build a barrack as soon as you get 200 wood. Send the builder to gather food (stocking food to age up) and have another wood-cutter to build ASAP 3 houses. (You may want to train a spearman to protect your villagers from early attacks).
6. Keep training villagers and when you reach 300 food, Age Up.
7. At this moment you should have 5 villagers gathering food and 7-9 gathering wood.
   After this I don't have an established order, but you'll want to build an archery range and a sacred ground, send a few villagers to gather gold and spam swordsman and slingers. 
   To control large armies use shortcuts. Double-click a swordsman and shift + (number1), do the same with slingers (2).

To quickly train a new units you may also use shortcuts. Double-click on a barrack and shift+(number6), archery range(7), and so on. So when you want to get a new swordsman you just need to press "6" and then "S" ("A"-1st unit[spearman]; "S"-2nd unit[swordsman];"D"-3rd unit[woad Raiders]; "F"-4th unit[champion]).